# Request.cookies.session is null

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I have this server side `sessionLogin.js`, which authenticates a user by getting their ID token and does verifyIdToken, and creates a session cookie with `firebase-admin.auth().createSessionCookie`.

Once the session cookie setting is done, it redirects the authenticated user to `AccountSummary.js` page.

This is working perfectly in local `firebase serve` but doesn't work in the actual QA site. QA sites gives "session empty" which, according to the code flow, happens when the request.cookies.session is null or not valid.

AccountSummary.js does the following:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
console.log("incoming session cookies: ")
console.log(req.cookies)
if(req.cookies && req.cookies.session){
// var sessionCookie=`${req.cookies.session}`;
    const sessionCookie = req.cookies.session || '';
// console.log('cookie: '+x)
   admin.auth().verifySessionCookie(
    sessionCookie, true /** checkRevoked */)
    .then((decodedClaims) => {
    var title = 'Account Summary';
    res.render('AccountSummary', {title: title});
    })
    .catch(error => {
    // Session cookie is unavailable or invalid. Force user to login.
    res.redirect('/SignIn.html');
    });
}else{
   res.status(401).send("Session empty");
}

});
```

SessionLogin.js:

```
router.post('/',function(req, res){
// var idToken = req.body.Token
const idToken = req.body.token.toString();
console.log("Recd ID token: "+ idToken)
admin.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken)
.then(function(decodedToken) {
  let uid = decodedToken.uid;
  console.log('uid: '+ uid)
  // Set session expiration to 1 day.
  const expiresIn = 60 * 60 * 24 * 1000;
  // Create the session cookie. This will also verify the ID token in the process.
  // The session cookie will have the same claims as the ID token.
  // To only allow session cookie setting on recent sign-in, auth_time in ID token
  // can be checked to ensure user was recently signed in before creating a session cookie.
  admin.auth().createSessionCookie(idToken, {expiresIn})
  .then(function(sessionCookie){
  // // Set cookie policy for session cookie.
  // if (req.protocol == 'https'){
     const options = { maxAge: expiresIn, httpOnly: true, secure: true};
// }else{
// const options = { maxAge: expiresIn, httpOnly: true, secure: false};
// }
     res.cookie('session', sessionCookie, options);
     console.log("setting session cookie suceeded");
     console.log('Cookie: ' +sessionCookie);
     res.send(JSON.stringify({status: 'success'}));
})
.catch(function(error){
console.log("setting session cookie failed");
res.status(401).send('UNAUTHORIZED REQUEST!');

});
}).catch(function(error) {
console.log("could not verify Token")
res.send(403).send('could not verify ID Token')
});

})
```

I troubleshooted this, and found that the cause is `req.cookies.session` does not show the session cookie. Sometimes it does, but still the `req.cookies.session` is empty.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Firebase Hosting + Cloud Functions, you will need to name the cookie `__session` instead of `session`. Firebase Hosting strips all other cookies from the request on the way to the server to preserve cache efficiency.

Comment: Thanks, it helped me figure it out. I found it is more than that though.
While doing res.cookie
1. Do not dpecify secure parameter in options 
2. Make sure you use secure: true. That means adding app use (cookieParser('password')) and adding "Secret: '$Secret$' " in the res.cookie options as well
3. make sure the set headers.
"    res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'private'); "
Then the cookie will set fine.
BTW, I got the headers information from another one of your posts, so thanks Michael.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, thought as a courtesy I will mention here so others may be benefitted as well.

The clinet-server stateless behavior introduces a lot of issues in web. I come from traditional "everything in server or local" environment, so had to take some time to digest the fact that there WILL be delays in processes, and NOT instantaneuos.

So, the cookie sets fine, but just takes some time. All you need to do, is to put a delay, a timer if you will in the client side code once the "Sign In" or "Login" button is pressed.

I put a delay like this for 4 seconds, which is astronomical, but at least we will be mostly sure that this is enough time to set the cookie.

```
             check_session_cookie()
             setTimeout(function(){ window.location.assign('/AccountSummary'); }, 4000);
      function check_session_cookie() {
        if (typeof getCookie("__session") === 'undefined'){
            //no cookie, sleep 250ms
            sleep(250,16)  //wait for 4 seconds for cookie. 
           } else {
            //have cookie
            return true
           }
      }
```

==> The flipside is that we still cannot be 100% certain. Some rare cases will still fail - but thats a given, there WILL be outliers.
I am sure I am doing something not perfect, so since someone more experienced and expert than myself will certainly see this post, I request them to please update with any suggestions.